# Distinguir formulários dentro do PHP

Tags: php, html, formulário

Há como distinguir formulários dentro do PHP, já que pretendo que toda formulário seja enviado para uma mesma função que esta estará encarregada de repassar o `$_GET` a devida função capaz de verificar a consistência do formulário.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `$_GET` normalmente não é usado com formulários e sim o `$_POST`.

O truque para distinguir é usar uma informação de identificação deste formulário. No caso o mais comum é usar um campo `hidden` no HTML.

```
<input type="hidden" name="NomeDoFormulario" value="InformacaoAdicional">
```

Aí você receberá um `$_POST["NomeDoFormulario"]` que terá como valor `"InformacaoAdicional"`. Pronto, você sabe de que formulário veio.

É possível utilizar outros tipos de campo também. Há quem goste de usar um campo `SUBMIT` mesmo para identificar. Afinal você pode ter cada botão de envio da aplicação/*site* com um nome diferente.

```
<button type="submit" name="meuForm" value="true">Enviar</button>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["meuForm"])) {
    //faz alguma coisa
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/DualForm.php).

É possível fazer algo semelhante com `$_GET` também, basta enviar um campo na *query* dele.

Comment: Era o que precisava obrigado.